# How to fix warnings 1082 (migration issue) and 1008 in Adobe Animate CC AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I debug the project, I got received 222 warnings and it contain only two warnings:

```
Warning: 1082: Migration issue: Method %s will behave differently in ActionScript 3.0 due to the change in scoping for the this keyword. See the entry for warning 1083 for additional information.
```

And the another one:

```
Warning: 1008: return value for function '%s' has no type declaration
```

And then, I provide a [screenshot of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0DBI.jpg). I'm finding a solution of it esp `Warning: 1082: Migration issue` but unfortunately, I found nothing. I read about `Warning: 1082: Migration issue` and it says that the codes import from AS2 to AS3, but in my case, I NEVER using AS2. And yes, I'm importing code from the another file, but in AS3. How can I fix these errors? Any ideas on how to solve it? Any suggestions or help will be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my code in my AS file:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public var mainmenu: MainMenu = new MainMenu();
        public var scrollinstructwin: ScrollInstructWin = new ScrollInstructWin();
        public var startopt: StartOpt = new StartOpt();
        public var learnopt: LearnOpt = new LearnOpt();
        public var newload: NewLoad = new NewLoad();
        public var propocon: PropoCon = new PropoCon();
        public var setcon: SetCon = new SetCon();
        public var relationcon: RelationCon = new RelationCon();
        public var scrollstorywin: ScrollStoryWin = new ScrollStoryWin();

        public function Main() {
            super();
            addChild(mainmenu);

            mainmenu.x = 350;
            mainmenu.y = 290;

            mainmenu.btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);//warning 1082
            mainmenu.btnInstruct.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, instruct);
        }
        public function start(event: MouseEvent) {//warning 1008
            removeChild(mainmenu);
            addChild(startopt);

            startopt.x = 350;
            startopt.y = 290;

            startopt.btnLearn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, learn);
            startopt.btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, laro);
            startopt.btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, back);
        }
        public function instruct(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(mainmenu);
            addChild(scrollinstructwin);

            scrollinstructwin.x = 36.20;
            scrollinstructwin.y = 21.50;

            scrollinstructwin.btnGi.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gi);
        }
        public function gi(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(scrollinstructwin);
            addChild(mainmenu);
        }
        public function back(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(startopt);
            addChild(mainmenu);
        }
        public function learn(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(startopt);
            addChild(learnopt);

            learnopt.x = 350;
            learnopt.y = 290;

            learnopt.btnPropo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, propo);
            learnopt.btnSets.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sets);
            learnopt.btnRelations.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, relations);
            learnopt.btnBack3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backo);
        }
        public function laro(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(startopt);
            addChild(newload);

            newload.x = 350;
            newload.y = 290;

            newload.btnNew.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, neww);
            newload.btnBack2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backu);
        }
        public function backo(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            addChild(startopt);
        }
        public function neww(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            addChild(scrollstorywin);

            scrollstorywin.x = 51.15;
            scrollstorywin.y = 30.05;
        }
        public function backu(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(newload);
            addChild(startopt);
        }
        public function propo(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            propocon.gotoAndStop(1);
            addChild(propocon);

            propocon.x = 414.80;
            propocon.y = 218.60;

            propocon.btnExit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, byeol);
        }
        public function byeol(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(propocon);
            addChild(learnopt);
        }
        /*propocon.btnBtm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, byl);
        public function byl(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(propocon);
            addChild(learnopt);
        }*/

        public function sets(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            addChild(setcon);

            setcon.x = 412.45;
            setcon.y = 225.00;
        }
        public function relations(event: MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(learnopt);
            addChild(relationcon);

            relationcon.x = 400.00;
            relationcon.y = 225.00;
        }
    }
}
```

I already comment one of the warnings in 1082 and 1008. What do you think is the cause of those warnings? Thanks!

Comment: there are so much warning and no code to check.
I think that you should provide some parts of code otherwise, it will difficult to figure us what's the issue.
Could you clarify your question and add the code where You receive Warnings?

Comment: My code is very long, I'll upload a file here.

Comment: The link is wrong.
Just post the lines mentioned in the Warning tab with some explanations please.
Read the help tab on stack overflow to see how to format the code!

Comment: I already comment the warnings on the affected code. Just the same with other code. My other code is in the movieclip timeline but it's just almost the same code.

Comment: I will take a look at this later, I'm busy now. Sorry

Comment: It's ok. I'm willing to wait. Thanks btw!

Comment: What does your MainMenu class look like?

Answer (score 1):

Warning 1008 is clear enough; your function definitions don't include a return type declaration.  None of your functions actually return anything, so this is harmless.  Still, to eliminate the warning, you can do:

```
public function start(event: MouseEvent):void {
```

in place of

```
public function start(event: MouseEvent) {
```

Comment: Alright! I removed `super()` and no more error appears. But still, thanks for your response.